# Embed DirectX Hwnd into NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, directx, node-webkit

I would like to embed a directx hwnd into a nodejs , my main idea is create the World Editor in HTML + JS + Node-Webkit, because of the flexibility html provides

i would like to have something like a HTML tag,  , maybe possible in conjunction with AngularJS

i came across i guy who was able to do it, but not idea how, can you guys point me in the right direction, if is possible any example?

http://n2liquid.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/direct3d-9-bindings-for-nodejs-%E2%80%94-sonettojss-baby-steps

Comment: node-webkit already supports WebGL, so why not use something like three.js or similar instead?

Comment: @mscdex because i would like to interact with my own engine that is written in DirectX 11

Answer (score 1):

Try **[node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi)**, maybe it would help.